# Make a phone call without default native app Android

Tags: android, phone-call

Is any way to make a phone call inside the app? I don't want to use the native app to make calls, just make the call inside the app (this means don't use the classic intent with the uri for start the activity of calls), I know that I need to have configurations for make the call, but I don't have a reference or documentation about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean phone calls the answer is no, you can't bypass the native phone app.